# what is the reasoning behind this 70-761 exam dump question

Tags: t-sql

I would like to understand question about conversion:
exam dump I'm working with has this question at least three times with 3 different solutions you approve or don't approve of   note that RegistrationNumber is defined as varchar(5) :

You run the following query:

```
SELECT UserId FROM tblVehicleRegistration
WHERE RegistrationNumber = 20012
AND RegistrationDate > '2016-01-01'
```

The query output window displays the following error message: “Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ‘AB012’ to data type int.”
You need to resolve the error.

Solution: You modify the Transact-SQL statement as follows:

```
SELECT UserId FROM tblVehicleRegistration
WHERE RegistrationNumber = '20012'
AND RegistrationDate > '2016-01-01'
```

answer says this does not work

Comment: Where does 'AB012’ come from?

Comment: I imagine it's (another) vehicle registration number, not that that gets us much further.

Comment: Yeah I figured 'AB012'  was in the vehicle registration field.  It really doesn't give any more info than what I posted.

Comment: Do you have the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would think the test is incorrect. Here is a simplified example:

```
declare @tblVehicleRegistration table (RegistrationNumber varchar(5))
insert into @tblVehicleRegistration(RegistrationNumber) VALUES('AB012')
SELECT * FROM @tblVehicleRegistration WHERE RegistrationNumber = 20012 --Fails as expected
SELECT * FROM @tblVehicleRegistration WHERE RegistrationNumber = '20012' --works as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

`SQL Server` will do a convertion in order to compare `'AB012'` and `20012`. If you check this link [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you will see that type `varchar`, wich is low precedence, needs to be converted to `int`, wich is high precedence, in order to make a comparison.

Comment: sure I can understand precedence.... but if the quotes are around the 20012 (as in the solution example we were to look at), wouldn't it be a varchar to varchar comparison?

Comment: Yes it would be. I'm wondering if it is wrong because of missing explicit casting

Answer (score 0):

I created a table and tried hands-on. It worked properly after casting or changing the integer value to a string with quotation marks.

Comment: Could you please provide the casting you have done.